# get sensor info every 5 seconds with UI running via multithreading C++ GTKMM

Tags: c++, multithreading, gtkmm

I have been trying to display sensor info in my UI(gtkmm3), using the c++ library "thread", Before calling the function `show_all_children();` I would run:

```
std::thread t1(get_sensor_info_thread);
t1.join();
```

Which calls this function (defined outside the constructor):

```
void get_sensor_info_thread() {
    while (true) {
        system("sensors");
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

My program executes but only shows the sensor info in the terminal every 5 seconds and doesn't show the UI, Ive tried starting the thread after the show all children function but the same happens, any help is appreciated :)

my constructor and get_sensor_info code:

```
#include "headers/MainWindow.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

void get_sensor_info_thread() {
    while (true) {
        system("sensors");
        sleep(5);
    }
}

MainWindow::MainWindow() :
mBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
headerBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL),
nBox1(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL),
lBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
rBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
sysBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL), 
fanBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
cpuBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL),
gpuBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL),
moboBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL) {

    set_title("NZXT Control UI");
    set_size_request(1000, 600);
    set_resizable(false);
    add(mBox);

    mBox.pack_start(headerBox, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
    mBox.pack_start(mNotebook);

    prevButton.set_image_from_icon_name("go-previous", Gtk::ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);
    nextButton.set_image_from_icon_name("go-next", Gtk::ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);

    headerBox.pack_end(nextButton, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
    headerBox.pack_end(prevButton, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

    nextButton.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::on_next_page));
    prevButton.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::on_prev_page));

    mNotebook.popup_enable();
    mNotebook.set_scrollable();
    mNotebook.append_page(nBox1, "Stats", true);
    mNotebook.append_page(nBox2, "Fans", true);
    mNotebook.append_page(nBox3, "RGB", true);

    nBox1.pack_start(lBox);
    nBox1.pack_start(rBox);

    lTitle.set_text("System statistics");
    rTitle.set_text("Fan/AIO speed statistics");
    
    lBox.pack_stbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.art(lTitle, false, 0);
    rBox.pack_start(rTitle, false, 0);

    sysFrame.set_label("System");
    fanFrame.set_label("Fans");
    lBox.add(sysFrame);
    rBox.add(fanFrame);

    cpuTemp = 0.0;
    gpuTemp = 0.0;
    moboTemp = 0.0;

    cpuLabel.set_text("CPU temperature: ");
    gpuLabel.set_text("GPU temperature: ");
    moboLabel.set_text("Motherboard temperature: ");
    cpuEntry.set_text(std::to_string(cpuTemp));
    gpuEntry.set_text(std::to_string(gpuTemp));
    moboEntry.set_text(std::to_string(moboTemp));

    cpuBox.pack_start(cpuLabel, false, 0);
    cpuBox.pack_end(cpuEntry, false, 0);
    gpuBox.pack_start(gpuLabel, false, 0);
    gpuBox.pack_end(gpuEntry, false, 0);
    moboBox.pack_start(moboLabel, false, 0);
    moboBox.pack_end(moboEntry, false, 0);

    sysBox.pack_start(cpuBox, false, 0);
    sysBox.pack_start(gpuBox, false, 0);
    sysBox.pack_start(moboBox, false, 0);

    sysFrame.add(sysBox);
    mBox.set_name("main-box");
    nBox1.set_name("stats-box");
    lBox.set_name("left-box");
    rBox.set_name("right-box");

    auto css = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
    css->load_from_path("style.css");
    Gtk::StyleContext::add_provider_for_screen
                   (Gdk::Screen::get_default(), css, 
                   GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

    show_all_children();

    std::thread t1(get_sensor_info_thread);
    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal and reproductible example.

Comment: @BobMorane I have added my constructor code

Comment: GTKmm has a way to run functions on timeout in its event loop. You don't need multithreading! See [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-timeouts.html.en). If on Linux, the `sensors` program is open source, so study its source code. Your program is similar to [xosview](http://xosview.sourceforge.net/) whose source code you could study

Comment: I think the timeout method is exactly what I need thank you :), Ive been trying to become better at reading through and understanding source code so ill look into the code for those, I appreciate your help

Comment: Why do you start a thread and immediately after join it again?

Comment: what do you mean ?